# Available work in a transition between two states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

How does one calculate the available energy in the transitions in the pictures below?

[image]

If I have a transition like $\alpha\rightarrow\beta$ surrounded by transitions coupled to a single temperature like on the left diagram, it seems reasonable to me to calculate the available energy as:

$\begin{align}
\Delta F_{\alpha\rightarrow\beta}  &=F_\alpha-F_\beta\\
&= E_{\alpha}-E_{\beta}-T_c( S_{\alpha\alpha}- S_{\beta\beta})\nonumber\\
 &= E_{\alpha}-E_{\beta}-T_c(-k_B\log{\rho_{\alpha\alpha}}+k_B\log{\rho_{\beta\beta}})\\
\end{align}
$

$\Delta F_{\alpha\rightarrow\beta} = 0  $ when the populations have the Boltzmann distribution with the cold temperature.

So the steady state deviation from the Boltzmann distribution at the cold (blue) temperature gives me the power output of the system between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

However the transition between 1 and $\beta$ in the right picture will give me zero available energy if I assign the states the numbers $F_\beta(T_c)$ and $F_1(T_h)$ and take the difference.

Is it true that the available energy in this case is bounded by the population inversion threshold such that we take away all available energy by stimulated emission as in [the 3-level amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_heat_engines_and_refrigerators)? It seems to me that this does not take into account the energy difference between 1 and $\beta$. How can I derive the available energy for the right picture?